# How can I run a C program in VS Code without getting "warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, permission-denied

I am trying to run the very simple hello world C program but when I finish my code and press on the run button around the top right corner for the first time I get a message that says:

```
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run"
```

After my first attempt, any attempts to press the run button give me this message:

```
"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
```

Either way, my output cannot be seen.

However, it does say `Build finished successfully` when I click the build terminal, and I can run the program by typing in `./filename` in the `cppdbg` terminal. That way, the output appears as it should. However, I want to see the same results when I press the run button.

Why is the run button not working and how can I fix it? I've searched this issue so many times but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

I tried opening VSCode as the administrator, downloading MingW compiler, editing launch and task JSON files, and changing compilers within VS Code but none of those methods brought any change.

Comment: The first thing would be to not run it through the debugger if you don't intend on debugging the code.

Comment: how do I not run it through the debugger? the only options I have are "C/C++: gcc build and debug active file",  "C/C++: gcc-11 build and debug active file", and "(gdb) Launch".

Comment: My VSCode system has two options to run: with and without debugging. Do you have these too? If yes, try the one without debugging. Does it work properly?

Comment: The options are "Debug C/C++ file" and "Run C/C++ file". I tried the latter but it is not working.

Comment: are you using the Code Runner extension?

Comment: Unless it is some default option that I don't know of, I am not using that extension.

Comment: Perhaps try googling the message. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/121)'s what cones out first for me. YMMV.